# Bottom toolbar menu item hint appears at the top

Tags: android, xamarin, android-5.0-lollipop, android-5.1.1-lollipop

I have an activity with 2 toolbars - one at the top and one at the bottom.
Both are from the `Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar` package. I am using Xamarin, but that shouldn't be the matter.

When i press and hold an menu item from the bottom toolbar, the action hint will be shown at the top (see screenshot). Is there a way to change that?

[image: Bottom Toolbar Hint Position on Top]

Answer (score 1):

This is a known AppCompat bug which has been fixed in version 22.2.1